# Javascript document.getElementById issue

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am a beginner to javascript, and am trying to learn how to use text boxes because I can't seem to find a page that is simple enough for me. This is what I have, but when I click the button, it just returns [object HTMLInputElement]. Could someone please tell me what i did wrong and help me fix it? Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function displaynumber(){
var number1= document.getElementById("num1");
alert(number1).value
}
</script>
<title>
ok
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Input the first number<input type="text" id="num1">
<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="displaynumber()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want `alert(number1.value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should correct your typo:

```
alert(number1).value
```

to

```
alert(number1.value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are alerting `number1` and then trying to read the `value` property of *the return value of `alert()`*.

Move the property accessor inside the function call.

```
alert(
    number1.value
);
```